# GDB 'gef>' spam when using `layout asm`

Tags: assembly, gdb

On both my machines, whenever I use GDB GEF, I have issues using `layout asm`.
It keeps spamming the `gef>` each time I scroll up, write anything or basically have any interaction with my terminal.

Is that a known bug in GEF? can it be fixed somehow?

I have tried to look it up but didn't find anything.
Here's a picture of what it looks like:
https://imgur.com/a/BcsgrY5